Implementing innap purchases on ionic android
I have an app in ionic 7 and cordova 12, this app is only used in android, now I want to implement an innap purchases.
My first option is to try to use Google Play Billing is there any other option you recommend me? After a purchase I need to know what was purchased on my backend server.
